# Run a java command in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, akka

I'm experimenting with Akka and I have setup the simple HelloWorld program mentioned in the documentation.

Since the program does not have an explicit main method defined, I need to invoke the program from the command line using:

```
java -classpath <all those JARs> akka.Main com.example.HelloWorld
```

My question is how do I do this from *within* Intellij? Probably very simple but I'm relatively new to Intellij.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into Edit Configuration:

```
Main Class: akka.Main
Program arguments: HelloWorld
```

Then run.

Answer (score 0):

[Creating and Editing Run/Debug Configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html)